# Declaring a global Variable in XSLT and assigning value in a loop

Tags: xslt, global-variables

Title is pretty much explaining my problem here. I came to know after some research that I cannot change value of xslt variable. Is it possible what I am trying to do.

Comment: No. It is not possible to change the value of a variable in XSLT. Luckily one never needs to.

Comment: thanks for your answer but I want to start a loop and compare each value with previous one for some processing, that's why I want to declare a variable outside and then change its value with each iteration, any idea how can I do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assign to <xsl:variable> after thedecleration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613753/assign-to-xslvariable-after-thedecleration)

Comment: What you want to do is of course possible, but not the way you want to do it. You must show your code if you want help.

Comment: It appears that you are looking to compare to the previous node.  Please see the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990290/xslt-comparing-preceding-siblings-elements-with-currents-node-element).