# XSLT : Assigning value to a variable after declaration

Tags: xslt, variable-assignment

Title is self explanatory. I need to assign a variable in a loop after declaring it outside.

Update:

I am still unable to do it. Below is what my code looks like

```
<fo:inline color="#2400c0" font-family="Courier" font-size="12px" font-weight="bold">
       <xsl:if test="string-length($XML1/ROOT/ROWSET/ROW/ORC/LISTORC/QST_ORC/LISTOBR/QST_OBR/RESULTSTATUS) != 0">
            <xsl:value-of
            select="$XML1/ROOT/ROWSET/ROW/ORC/LISTORC/QST_ORC/LISTOBR/QST_OBR/RESULTSTATUS" />
        </xsl:if>
</fo:inline>
```

This piece of code lies inside loops. QST_OBR in LISTOBR can have one of following set of values `{'P','F','X'}`. I want to print 'X' if anyone of the QST_OBR has value 'X'. If no one has 'X', then I need to look for 'P'. 'F' should be printed only if all values are 'F'.

Here are some cases
for set`{'P','X','F'}` printed value should be 'X'
for set `{'P','P','F','F'}` should be 'P'
and 'F' only if all values in list are 'F'.

Comment: There are so many examples here. Just do a search.

Comment: Just correct the spelling of your title and enter it into the search box, you will get about 1400 hits and the top ones all answer your question. (Or rather, they tell you how to rephrase the question: explain your problem, not your incorrect attempt at solving it)

Comment: How is it? can you able to do it. If there is any problem share your code here.

Comment: @ambarox, thank you for your interest. I have posted some updates and my code as well. Still in need of someone's help.

Answer (score 1):

Please Refer this Link
[Assign to <xsl:variable> after thedecleration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613753/assign-to-xslvariable-after-thedecleration) According to that

```
No. XSLT variables are read-only. They cannot be assigned multiple times.
XSLT is not an imperative programming language like, say, PHP. Reassigning 
variables is both impossible and unnecessary.
```

Please Check the Accepted Answer The gentlemen Who gave that answer provide a method to do it. Hope it will help you.